# AWS Lambda ramps up to 15 concurrent executions and then stops executing code inside lambda_handler before dropping to 1 concurrent execution

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, function, aws-lambda, concurrency

I have an AWS Lambda function with a timeout of 900 seconds (15 minutes). It was setup to run every 20 minutes using an EventBridge schedule. Also, in the code, there's logic so that once it reaches 14 minutes of runtime, it ends the function. It was running perfectly.

Then, I changed the reserved concurrency limit to 15 for the function, and changed the EventBridge schedule to every one minute. This is where it started getting weird.

[image]

The function was firing every one minute, but once it reached 15 concurrent executions, it appeared to have stopped executing the code contained inside the lambda_handler function. Then the number of concurrent executions dropped from 15 to 1. What I mean by the function code not being executed is this:

[image]

Note how the whole execution takes 1.74ms. I put a print() statement right below the lambda_handler() to see if it got executed but it doesn't even get that far. It looks as if the function gets called, but none of the code within it gets executed. Interestingly, if I update the function and redeploy, it returns to running normally again and executing the code. This would point to cold starts working ok, but warm instances not behaving correctly.

I enabled x-ray, and all it's really showing is that the function execution lasted 2ms. Is there something else I can look at?

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update 1 (Code of Lambda Function)**

Note - I hid the implementation of process_symbol() as it's just downloading data for a stock symbol and saving it to S3.

```
import os
import json
import s3fs
import urllib3

from datetime import datetime

MAX_RUNNING_TIME_SECONDS = 900

# Timing
start_execution_time = datetime.now()

def get_execution_time_remaining():

    return MAX_RUNNING_TIME_SECONDS - (datetime.now() - start_execution_time).seconds

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print('Execution beginning')

    symbols = []
    execution_time_remaining = get_execution_time_remaining()

    while execution_time_remaining > 60:

        # Get next symbol to load
        symbol_metadata = get_next_symbol_to_load()

        if symbol_metadata:
    
            symbol = symbol_metadata[0]
            symbols.append(symbol)
        
            # process_symbol(symbol)
            # update_rds(symbol)

        execution_time_remaining = get_execution_time_remaining()
        print(f'execution_time_remaining = {execution_time_remaining}')

    return_message = ''
    current_time_text = datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S.%f')

    if symbols:
        return_message = f"Successfully saved {', '.join(symbols)} to the cloud at {current_time_text}."
    else:
        return_message = f'Successfully execution at {current_time_text} but no symbols were processed.'

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": return_message,
    }
```

**Update 2**

Also noteworthy, after it ramps up to 15 concurrent executions and stops executing the code contained in the lambda function, there's a break of about 80-90 minutes, before it somehow starts executing the function code again.

[image]

Comment: I think without seeing some of the code we won't be able to really solve this. The `Execution beginning` output seems to indicate that your code is being executed. My guess is that something is unhappy (or very happy and returning a cached result) with the execution context being reused but without seeing code it's nothing more than a guess. Another suspect is your stop-if-at-14-mins-logic as it may use global variables that aren't being reset properly.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. See code added to question. I was previously returning the same return_message text, i.e. 'Success' before I saw your comment. I since updated it to return a unique string, thinking this might trick the Lambda function into not caching the result. This hasn't helped unfortunately. Also I hid the implementation of two functions within the code as they were just responsible for making external API calls and downloading CSV files.

Comment: @Maurice, I moved the start_execution_time = datetime.now() to inside the lambda_handler and the number of concurrent instances is stable at 15. I think 15 will be the max in this case because the timeout per function is 15 minutes and it is invoked every 1 minute. Will add an answer below and give you kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Maurice hinted at, there was a global variable affecting the execution of the code in a concurrency scenario. The assignment:

```
start_execution_time = datetime.now()
```

which was previously assigned above the lambda_handler(), when moved to inside it, resulted in the concurrency working as expected. This blog post was also useful:

https://pfisterer.dev/posts/aws-lambda-container-reuse/

as it discussed the how lambda reuses containers and what affect that might have on executions.